# How to get current page menu item ancestor name wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to know how to retrieve as variable the name of the current page. 
For exemple, My menu is like :

```
Item 1
Item 2 => sub-item 1
```

Item 1 & 2 are custom links. sub-item1 is my page.

When I'm on this page, I want to retrieve "Item 2" name (to build my custom breadcumbs)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**BREADCRUMBS:**

Here is a breadcrumbs function that work with the hierarchy of your menu. Add this to your theme's 'functions.php'.

```
function my_menu_breadcrumb($theme_location, $separator = ' &gt; ') {
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    if ( isset( $locations[ $theme_location ] ) ) {
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $theme_location ] );
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
        _wp_menu_item_classes_by_context( $menu_items );
        $breadcrumbs = array();

        foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {         
            if ($menu_item->current) {
                $breadcrumbs[] = "<span title=\"{$menu_item->title}\">{$menu_item->title}</span>";
            }
            else if ($menu_item->current_item_ancestor) {
                $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"{$menu_item->url}\" title=\"{$menu_item->title}\">{$menu_item->title}</a>";
            }
        }

        echo implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
     }
}
```

You can then call as `<?php my_menu_breadcrumb('header-menu'); ?>` where 'header-menu' is the menu location name. In the loop, `$menu_item->title` will return page title and `$menu_item->url` it's URL.

**PARENT MENU TITLE:**

Here is the function to get parent menu item title(s) of current page - add this to your theme's 'functions.php'.

```
function my_menu_parent($theme_location) {
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    if ( isset( $locations[ $theme_location ] ) ) {
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $theme_location ] );
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
        _wp_menu_item_classes_by_context( $menu_items );
        $breadcrumbs = array();

        foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {         
            if ($menu_item->current_item_ancestor) {
                $breadcrumbs[] = $menu_item->title;
            }
        }

        return $breadcrumbs;
     }
}
```

You can then call as below where 'header-menu' is the menu location name.

```
$parentitems = my_menu_parent( 'header-menu' );
foreach ( $parentitems as $parentitem ) {
    echo $parentitem."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Hi @Outsource Wordpress, thanks for your answer, great function that's better than mine ! Can just give me the way to get only the parent name please

Comment: Beautiful !! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

***You can user this***

```
$pagename = get_query_var('pagename');  
if ( !$pagename && $id > 0 ) {  
// If a static page is set as the front page, $pagename will not be set. Retrieve it from the queried object  
$post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();  
$pagename = $post->post_name;  
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't need the page name... I need the menu parent name of the page !

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tutorials and code snippets online describing how to show the active page’s children (or if on one of those children, the active page’s siblings) as a sub-menu in WordPress. Usually something like this:

```
<?php
$ref_post = empty($post->post_parent) ? $post->ID : $post->post_parent;
$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$ref_post.'&echo=0');
if ($children) {
echo "<ul>$children</ul>";
}
?>
```

for ref:-https://www.minddevelopmentanddesign.com/blog/showing-current-pages-parents-sub-menu-items-custom-nav-menu-wordpress/